# In TCL how can I pass a list as one variable through command line args?

Tags: tcl

I have tried this:

```
<tcl_interpreter> mytcl.tcl first {1 2 3 4 5 6}
```

I would like arg1 to be "first" and arg2 to be the list {1 2 3 4 5 6}. So $argc should be 2. But $argc gives me 7 and each element of {1 2 3 4 5 6} is treated as a separate argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Just had to put {1 2 3 4 5 6} inside quotation marks. So:

```
<tcl_interpreter> mytcl.tcl first "{1 2 3 4 5 6}"
```

would produce what I am looking for. It will treat {1 2 3 4 5 6} as one list of integers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use quotes instead of braces. The interpreter doesn't know that braces mean a list, because they mean a list within Tcl. If you want to pass a list, you do it like this:

```
<tcl_interpreter> mytcl.tcl first "1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

If you have something like this in your `mytcl.tcl`, then you get `3` printed:

```
[lindex [lindex $argv 1] 2]
```

---

Note that using `"{1 2 3 4 5 6}"` will give the script a list, containing one element, that element itself being a list containing 6 elements.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's the opposite. Just tried it. If you use "1 2 3 4 5 6" then [lindex $argv 0] will be a single variable that contains a list. So [lindex $argv 1] would not exist for example. This is not what I want. If you use "{1 2 3 4 5 6}" then [lindex $argv 0] would just be 1 and [lindex $argv 1] would be 2 and so on. This is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Arash That was not your question. `[lindex $argv 0]` for your question should return `first` and `[lindex $argv 1]` should return a list, not a list of a list...